# What is the scientific purpose of external cables for cyborgs/androids?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell

I've seen the *Ghost in the Shell* movie and bits of the anime, but the only thing that still leaves me wondering is what those external cables attached to the body are used for. If this concept is more than just for visual aesthetic, then **what is the purpose of these cables?** Is it for data/consciousness uploading? Electricity recharging?

[image]

Comment: Typically diagnostics, maintenance, charging, etc all need to be done from external ports/cables.

Comment: If you think that's bad; just wait until you see the old way! ;)

Comment: Now I'm curious about this "old way". Please tell me more. XD

Comment: @CodeMaster - I'm assuming the old-style cables are NSFW

Comment: "*Those things are iconic, and if they weren't in there, people would be upset, myself included. We are in this Ghost in the Shell world. Everything is cables. And early on, people were like, 'Why are there cables in everything?' Well, it is Ghost in the Shell, and if there were no cables, it wouldn't be Ghost in the Shell, so I am going to defer to the style of Ghost in the Shell and put cables in everything.*" - https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/538qnn/ghost-in-the-shell-director-rupert-sanders

Comment: @Valorum Well, that doesn't need to be explored further, luckily.

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-universe, the decision was purely stylistic. The original show contained cables (noting that it largely pre-dated ubiquitous *wireless everything*) and the director wanted to retain that aesthetic.

> If I wanted to make something that was closer in spirit to the anime,
> and there were things as a fan of the original that I felt had to be
> in there, that I really needed to cinematize and to translate much
> closer to the original. The water fight, exploding geisha heads, Major
> on the tank, Major jumping off the roof.
>
> **Those things are iconic**, and if they weren't in there, people would be
> upset, myself included. We are in this Ghost in the Shell world.
> Everything is cables. And early on, people were like, **'Why are there
> cables in everything?' Well, it is Ghost in the Shell, and if there
> were no cables, it wouldn't be Ghost in the Shell, so I am going to
> defer to the style of Ghost in the Shell and put cables in everything.**
>
> <sub><sup>[We Talked to the 'Ghost in the Shell' Director About Weed, Whitewashing, and Cyberpunk](https://www.vice.com/en/article/538qnn/ghost-in-the-shell-director-rupert-sanders)</sup></sub>

---

In-universe, I think we can reasonably assume that these are the typical array of power, diagnostic and maintenance cables that you see on [robots that are being worked on](https://wevolver-project-images.s3.amazonaws.com/0.hyu229ckny7Figure%201.jpg).

> In fact, that anachronism actually worked with the sensibility that
> Sanders and Roelfs wanted to convey. Though the movie is set in a
> bustling future filled with advanced robotics and augmented reality as
> the new normal, there are some old callbacks. Roelfs wanted to retain
> some of the most iconic images from the original anime, while
> suggesting that we had not fully overcome the laws of gravity and **the
> need for solid connections.**
>
> “It could be all in one chip, but we didn’t want to do it” **“Everybody
> is connected, through mind-coms and all kinds of things, but we also
> took something from the original anime, that everything’s still
> connected by a lot of cables,”** Roelfs explains. “So you go ahead in
> time with the holograms, and you go back in time, with the cables. The
> villain’s lair had a ridiculous amount of cables. It could be all in
> one chip, but we didn’t want to do it, so that’s the ode to the
> original manga.”
>
> <sub><sup>[WHY 'GHOST IN THE SHELL' INTRODUCED HOLOGRAMS BUT KEPT THE CABLES](https://www.inverse.com/article/29570-ghost-in-the-shell-changes-from-the-anime-design-holograms)</sup></sub>

Comment: One other reason why it might continue is that a physical connection can be very difficult to hack remotely. Although, maybe in part for that reason, once hacked, it can take a while to root out the replaced equipment.